# What is the name of this visualization with a circle and internal arcs?

Tags: visualization

I came across this visualization where there is a circle with data points on the circle and internal lines (arcs or edges) between the points on the circle. What is the name of this type of visualization?

[image]

How would I generate it from a 2-D table like the one below? I want the points A, B, C, D, and E on the circle and the value from point i to j to be an arc between them. Would something like `d3.js` be able to generate it?

[image]

Comment: I think this is circos plot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [chord diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chord_diagram). It is usuallly generated from a square matrix like the one you have. This can be done with specific libraries at least in R ([circlize](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/circlize/versions/0.4.11) package) and Python ([plotly](https://plotly.com/python/v3/filled-chord-diagram/)). It's also possible [to do it with d3.js](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/chord.html) but apparently not so easily.

General advice: I find the "X Graph Gallery" websites quite convenient for exploring different types of graphs: [R graph gallery](https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/), [Python graph gallery](https://python-graph-gallery.com/) and [D3 graph gallery](https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/).

Comment: Thank you. Those graph galleries are very helpful.